# Windows azure table logging, querying issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, azure, azure-table-storage

We are using windows azure table for logging errors within our applications hosted inside either worker role or web role. We are logging sufficient information in table so that it is easy to identify which role, which component of a class has logged error.

Component Id (fully qualified class name) is used partition key and random unique Guid is as row key.

This logging information is displayed on ASP.NET MVC website, where administrator can search this log based on filter criteria like component id, date range, role identifier, severities etc.

This works fine till table is small. Once azure table contains huge amount of records(200000 or more), filter on azure table is taking too long time and it times out. We are using .NET azure storage API to query tables.

We also wanted a paging on returned resultset, but it looks like in azure table we don't get exact count for records returned.

We tried using azure storage API to apply filter and get data based on current page number, but its not working. I understand that we may have to redesign our table structure, especially partitionkey and rowkey, but not sure how to proceed with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a lot of custom filters, table storage may not offer the best performance. Consider to use SQL Azure if possible. To increase table storage performance, you can try:

1. Do not use custom fitlers. Only filter the result using partition/row key. This will give you the best performance.
2. Make each partition small. Scanning a small partition is faster than scanning a large partition.

As for paging, unless you have a cross partition query, paging should work as expected. If you ask for 20 entities, exactly 20 entities (if there're so many) will be returned. But if a partition boundary is encountered, a new page is required. For example, if a partition boundary is encountered when the 15th matching entity is found, only 15 entities will be returned in this request. You have to create a new request to query the next partition. If you keep partitions small, you may encounter this problem more frequently. So you need to design the system to automatically query the next partition if needed.

Also keep in mind table storage's paging is not based on page number. It is based on continuation token. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135718.aspx for more information.

Comment: we are planning to use sql azure as azure log table does not offer good options for querying it.

Answer (score 1):

You only have 2 'indexed' properties when using table storage, being your partition key and your row key. Searching on other fields will be very slow if you have loads of data.

When implementing a paging system or when you want to order your data you should play with the row key. The row key defines the order of your data (the sort order is lexicographical).

I suggest you take a look at Steve's blog post for more information on sorting and ordering your data: [Using Numbers as Keys in Windows Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure)

Comment: Thanks Sandrino. I have gone through the link you have provided. It will only solve the problem of ordering. It would not solve the other problems

Answer (score 0):

In such case I would suggest logger that I have written for storing logs in Azure Table - QLog. You can obtain it via NuGet. It comes with a QLogBrowser that will allow you to query logs in the manner that you want. GitHub project site is [here](https://github.com/sobanieca/QLog).